# How to store data in strings?

Tags: python

This is the question:

> Write a function month() that takes a number between 1 and 12 as input and returns the three-character abbreviation of the corresponding month. Do this without using an `if` statement, just string operations. Hint: Use a string to store the abbreviations in order.

This is what I have so far:

```
def month (x):
    storage=" JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec"
    k=storage.find(storage[x])
    print(storage[k],storage[k+1],storage[k+2])

month(0)
```

Comment: Looks like homework. Hint: Each month abbreviation is 3 letters long , not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def month(x):
     months = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec"
     return months[3*(x-1):3*x]
```

Hey, three letter abbreviations readily lend themselves to string slicing.

Comment: Please explain _why_ your code solves the asker's problem.